# Defining $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and usage.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Construct a definition for the statement $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$. Then, show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$

Definition: We say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists some number $N$ such that if $x>N$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

To show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$, we need to show that if $x>N$, then $|\frac{1}{x}|<\epsilon$. Choose $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and assume $x>N\rightarrow x>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rightarrow\frac{1}{x}<\epsilon$. Because $\frac{1}{x}$ is positive, $|\frac{1}{x}|<\epsilon$, and thus we have just proven that $x>N\rightarrow|\frac{1}{x}|<\epsilon$, which means that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$

Would this be a good definition for the infinite limit?

Comment: Looks good to me. Your proof is fine as well. You might want to rewrite the line "assume $x>N\rightarrow x>1/\epsilon\rightarrow1/x<\epsilon$", it's a bit confusing as stated.

Comment: To be more pedantic, maybe one would demand you write, "... exists some number $N \color{red}{\in \Bbb R}$...".